# Can static template functor be inlined by compiler?

Tags: c++, functor

I have read following questions:

1. [Template functors vs functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359041/template-functors-vs-functions)
2. [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)
3. [C++ function template partial specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061456/c-function-template-partial-specialization)

And I understand what `C++ functors` are good for. But I can't deduce what will happen if will do the following:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int state>
class Foo {
public:
    static Foo_func() { /* Do something */ };
}

// Partial specialization:
// -- state == 1
template <typename T>
class Foo <T, 1> {
public:
    static Foo_func() { /* Do something */ };
}

template <typename F>
void call_func(F func) {

    // Do something... //

    func();

    // Do something... //
}

int main() {
    Foo <double, /*state*/ 1> obj;

    // Case 1:
    call_func(obj.Foo_func);

    // Case 2:
    call_func(Foo<double, /*state*/ 1>::Foo_func);
}
```

In which scenario compiler will be able to inline `Foo_func()` ?

Comment: Look at the assembly and see what the compiler does.  A good resource to use is https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for a lot of reasons. For what it's worth, the compiler should be able to inline the calls to `func`, but I suspect it will only do so if `call_func` itself is inlined. [In this simple code the compiler inlines everything](https://godbolt.org/g/8KmlTv).

Comment: You can't reliably deduce optimizations in general, always check the asm. FWIW Clang and GCC both inline these in this case, but they might not always do it.

Comment: btw, `functor`'s  are function object. A class with `operator()()` overloaded. You have tagged the question with functor. but all you are using function pointer. Also note that you don't need to instantiate an object of a class to use a `static` member function.

Answer (score 5):

> But I can't deduce what will happen if will do the following

It's not possible to *deduce* what will happen, you just have to try it and see.

Inlining is an optimization, not a language feature. When and whether it happens depends on your compiler, its version, how you configure it, and possibly lots of other context around the (possibly in-lined) call site.